# OnePlus 5 Black Screen after Pie

Tags: updates, boot, screen, 9.0-pie, oneplus-5

My OnePlus 5 after the Pie OTA update wont show the screen. after rebooting, it only shows the 'android' logo and then the screen goes completely blank(black). I can sense that the phone is turning on and working since I can feel the vibrations on the lock screen and random apps opening. I tried going to the recovery but even the recovery is blank but I can feel the touch vibrations. 
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I sucessfully upgraded my One Plus 5 T to Anroid 9 last night and this morning it was just a black screen and I could do nothing. I knew it wasn't the battery as it was on charge for the upgrade. I got it to work again by holding the volume down key and the power key for 10 seconds then it rebooted and my phone is alive again.

EDIT: Since posting this I have realised that once the phone locks again I can't unlock it! :(